# Flutter display AlertDialog based on server response

Tags: flutter

I am currently trying to make a login screen. So far I was able to figure things out by myself by following their documentation.

However I want to implement a certain thing which I am currently unable to do and not really sure how to proceed with it.

The basic algorithm is:

- Send request.
- Receive data. [If data good -> true, if bad-> false]
- If received true -> move to the next screen.
- If received false -> display alert dialog with message (wrong username of password)

I haven't studied navigation yet, but I saw a documentation page [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics). I was planning on following that. Please let me know if there is something else I need to know.

When it comes to alert dialog - I am aware on how to display it, but when I am trying to do so, it gives me this error:

> The return type 'Future' isn't a Widget as required by closure's context

I understand the message, yet due to the fact that I am quite new to flutter I am not sure what would be the correct way of displaying alert dialog with custom message in my case. Please help me out here.

I will post the code below.

login_ui.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_first_flutter_app/remotedatasource/httpClient.dart';

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final _loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _httpClient = new HttpClient();

  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future<bool> userSignIn;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    usernameController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _loginFormKey,
        child: Center(
            child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
                    height: 240,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 40, top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 15, top: 10, right: 15, bottom: 10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                ),
                                hintText: 'Username'),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Field is empty';
                              } else {
                                return null;
                              }
                            },
                            controller: usernameController,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                ),
                                hintText: 'Password'),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Field is empty';
                              } else {
                                return null;
                              }
                            },
                            controller: passwordController,
                            obscureText: true,
                            enableSuggestions: false,
                            autocorrect: false,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: 45,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if (_loginFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        userSignIn = _httpClient.signIn(
                                            usernameController.text,
                                            passwordController.text);
                                      });
                                    }
                                  }, //TODO->Send login data
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Submit',
                                    textScaleFactor: 1.25,
                                  ))),
                          (userSignIn!=null)?FutureBuilder<bool>(
                            future: userSignIn,
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if(snapshot.hasData) {
                                  return showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (context) {
                                        return AlertDialog(
                                          content: Text(
                                              'Your data: \n username = ${usernameController.text} \n password = ${passwordController.text}'),
                                        );
                                      });
                                } else {
                                  return Text('Failure');
                                }
                              }
                          ) : null
                        ]
                    ))
                ));
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_first_flutter_app/loginscreen/ui/login_ui.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
              currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
            currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Login',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            body: LoginForm(),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

httpClient.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:my_first_flutter_app/util/util.dart';

class HttpClient {
  final String _loginURL = 'https://myurl/api/signin.api.php';

  Future<bool> signIn(String username, String password) async {
    final body = jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
      'qpalzm': getAccessKey()
    });

    final response = await http.post(_loginURL,
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      return true;
    } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      return false;
    } else {
      throw Exception('An unknown error occurred');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2-3 things:

(1)   Instead of a Future set the variable as only bool

```
  bool userSignIn;
```

(2) await your request. So instead of

```
onPressed: () {
                                    if (_loginFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        userSignIn = _httpClient.signIn(
                                            usernameController.text,
                                            passwordController.text);
                                      });
                                    }
                                  },
```

use

```
onPressed: () async { //Use Async here
                                    if (_loginFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        userSignIn = await _httpClient.signIn( //await here
                                            usernameController.text,
                                            passwordController.text);
                                      });
                                    }
                                  },
```

(3) Your show Dialog does not return Widget. It draws a pop-up, under which you can have widgets. So,

```
showDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (context) {
return userSignIn ? LoginSuccessWidget() : LoginFailureWidget(); //Build what you want to show when login succeeds or fails, which could be AlertDialogs or Simple dialog or any other
           });
```